# Is there an acceptable way of asking this question on ELU?

Tags: support

I need help coming up with a tricky simile.  I tried asking on Writers SE but it got closed.  I was advised to ask on Writers Chat, but there has been no response.

Is there a workable way of setting [this question](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/26051/13494) up on ELU?

Comment: It sounds like a creativity related request. I doubt there can be a good objective non-opinionated answer on ELU.

Comment: No. Writing advice questions are not allowed here. If Writers won't allow them either then I guess keep trying chat. You can try the ELU chat too of course.

Comment: One way to overcome EL&U's straightjacket would be to focus on the expression `passing grades` which is a "true" point,  but fails to tell the whole picture. You could ask for the name of a rhetorical device which presents a fact as being representative of the truth, when it clearly omits details. You could also ask if there is a common idiom which describes this form of bias or slant.

Comment: But asking users to come up with an original simile, would only invite  close votes for being POB.

Comment: I do wish moderators could move comments into answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking users to come up with an original simile, would only invite close votes for being POB.

One way to overcome EL&U's straitjacket would be to focus on the expression *passing grades* used in the official document, which makes a "true" point, but fails to tell the whole picture.

You could ask for the name of a rhetorical device which presents a fact as being representative of the truth, when it clearly omits key details. You could also ask if there is a common idiom which describes this form of bias or slant.

You could create your own simile/metaphor and ask if a known one already exists— this could however lead you onto a slippery slope, and users might argue that the question is POB, or too broad. On the other hand, if the question ignites interest and good suggestions, it's rare a popular question gets closed on its first day.

Good luck!

Comment: I *think* Andrew Leach was commenting about Curiousdanni and my comments. when he wished mods could change comments into answers, in the comment he left in the comment section.

Comment: Yes, I think so too.  He really should have pinged you.  At any rate, I'm glad you noticed, because now I can Accept With Enthusiasm. Thank you, it worked!  Now all I have to do is convince Edwin to write a &%%$*! answer for once in his life.

Comment: @aparente001 well, I'm just pleased my suggestion helped you obtain the answer you needed.